# doxygen: How to link to an external URL with # (hash) sign?

Tags: latex, doxygen

I am trying to link an `URL` which contains a `#` (hash) sign, see upstream code [here](https://github.com/malaterre/GDCM/blob/master/Source/MediaStorageAndFileFormat/gdcmImageRegionReader.h#L31):

- http://dicom.nema.org/medical/dicom/current/output/chtml/part05/sect_8.2.html#para_4bcb841e-c6bf-4e26-82a5-3fad3c942da0

Everything works as expected with `HTML` output, but things gets nasty with `LaTeX` output (`PDF`). It fails with:

```
! Illegal parameter number in definition of \Hy@tempa.
<to be read again>
                   p
l.153 ...ageref{classgdcm_1_1ImageRegionReader}}{}

?
```

Looking at the generated code, I see:

```
\href{http://dicom.nema.org/medical/dicom/current/output/chtml/part05/sect_8.2.html#para_4bcb841e-c6bf-4e26-82a5-3fad3c942da0}
```

I cannot simply escape the `#` sign with a backslash since it would break the `HTML` output (but fix the `LaTeX` output). I found [on the web](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/12860/25980) that including `bigfoot` before `hyperref` can solve this sort of issue, but this did not work for me using the following trick in the doxyfile:

```
@@ -1650,7 +1650,7 @@ PAPER_TYPE             = letter
 # If left blank no extra packages will be included.
 # This tag requires that the tag GENERATE_LATEX is set to YES.

-EXTRA_PACKAGES         =
+EXTRA_PACKAGES         = bigfoot

 # The LATEX_HEADER tag can be used to specify a personal LaTeX header for the
 # generated LaTeX document. The header should contain everything until the first
```

Is there anything simple to include a URL with `#` sign that works for both `HTML` and `LaTeX` output ?

---

EDIT: I found out that doxygen generate the following code:

```
% Hyperlinks (required, but should be loaded last)
\usepackage{ifpdf}
\ifpdf
  \usepackage[pdftex,pagebackref=true]{hyperref}
\else
  \usepackage[ps2pdf,pagebackref=true]{hyperref}
\fi
```

So I cannot explicitly `\usepackage{hyperref}` after `\usepackage{bigfoot}` since this creates some sort of conflict.

```
Package hyperref Message: Driver (autodetected): hpdftex.

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hpdftex.def
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/rerunfilecheck.sty))

! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package hyperref.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.101 \else
```

Comment: Please add a minimal example (source file + Doxyfile) and / or file a bug report at https://bugzilla.gnome.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=doxygen

Comment: Reported [here](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=769977)